# Counting variable not working and I'm not sure why

Tags: python

im trying to make a variable that counts up but it comes up with this error:

local variable 'cobblestone' referenced before assignment

```
@bot.command()
async def mine(ctx):
  cobblestone = cobblestone + int('1')
  await ctx.send('the sever now has',cobblestone,'cobblestone')
```

I'm pretty new to coding, so if the answer is really obvious, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cobblestone` only exists within the function. You need it to be global.  It also doesn't exist when you add `cobblestone` to it at first.  You want something like this:

```py
cobbleston = 0

@bot.command
async def mine(ctx):
  global cobblestone
  cobblestone += 1
  await ctx.send('the sever now has',cobblestone,'cobblestone')
```

Note that the easiest way to get an int.... is to write an int, rather than cast a string.

### Global variables

If a variable is defined in global scope it *is* available inside a function (or other inclosing scope) unless shadowed.  So this works:

```py
x = 0

def incr():
    print(x)

incr()
```

But Python doesn't allow you to reassign global variables without explicitly declaring them as global:

```py
x = 0

def incr():
    x += 1
    print(x)

incr()
```

Raises `UnboundLocalError`, whereas:

```py
x = 0

def incr():
    global x
    x += 1
    print(x)

incr()
```

Behaves as expected.

If x is a muteable, this is not needed, because *the name x is never changed*: we don't move `x` to point at another integer, but we mutate it.  So this is fine:

```py
x = [0] # lists are muteable

def incr():
    x[0] += 1
    print(x)

incr()
```

Comment: `global` is not necessary

Comment: @HamidrezaKhorammfar it is: see update.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create that variable outside the function to do this.

like this:

```
cobblestone = 0

@bot.command()
async def mine(ctx):
  cobblestone += 1
  await ctx.send('the sever now has',cobblestone,'cobblestone')
```

Comment: you need `global` as well, since you're mutating it between calls

Comment: @2e0byo global is not necessary – Because the out-of-function variable is introduced in the global section .. If we make the variable in the function, we need a global

Comment: on the contrary, because we are reassigning the name x to a different int. If x were a list it would behave

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to defining a `global` outside the function is to create an attribute in the function itself:

```
>>> def mine():
...     try:
...         mine.cobblestone += 1
...     except AttributeError:
...         mine.cobblestone = 1
...     print(mine.cobblestone)
... 
>>> mine()
1
>>> mine()
2
>>> mine()
3
>>> mine()
4
```